# raw_input and print in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, printing, raw-input

I have a thread which can print some text on the console and the main program have a `raw_input` to control the thread.

My problem is when I'm writing and the thread too I get something like this:

```
-->whatiwWHATTHETHREADWRITErite
```

but I would like to get some thing like this

```
WHATTHETHREADWRITE
-->whatiwrite
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to syncronize your input with the thread output preventing them from happening at the same time.

You can modify the main loop like:

```
lock = threading.lock()

while 1:
    raw_input()     # Waiting for you to press Enter
    with lock:
        r = raw_input('--> ')
        # send your command to the thread
```

And then lock the background thread printing:

```
def worker(lock, ...):
    [...]
    with lock:
        print('what the thread write')
```

**In short when you `Press Enter` you will stop the thread and enter in "input mode".**

To be more specific, every time you `Press Enter` you will:

- wait for the lock to be available
- acquire the lock
- print `-->` and wait for your command
- insert your command
- send that command to the thread
- release the lock

So your thread **will be stopped only if it tries to print when you are in "input mode"**,
and in your terminal you'll get something like:

```
some previous output

---> your input
THE THREAD OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a lock, and perform all input and output while holding the lock:

```
import threading

stdout_lock = threading.Lock()

with stdout_lock:
    r = raw_input()

with stdout_lock:
    print "something"
```

Comment: @Guillaume: Can I ask you how can this work for you? I thought that you needed the input channel to be left open to control the thread.

Comment: Yes I have make something like in your post!

Answer (score -1):

Use something like [curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) to write the background task output to half the screen and your input/control stuff on the other half.

You can also fiddle with [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) on most terminals.