# Get user input while printing to the screen

Tags: python, multithreading, input, while-loop, output

I would like to get user input while printing to the screen. I researched this a lot. but didn't find anything. I'm not very advanced with class programming in Python, so I didn't understand the other examples on stackoverflow.

Example:

```
import time

def user_input():
    while True:
        raw_input("say smth: ")

def output():
    while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        print "hi"

input()
output()
```

I want the prompt to stay, even if the output is printing "hi". I already tried an example, but the input prompt disappears even if it is in a `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's go over your code

```
import time

def user_input():
    while True:
        raw_input("say smth: ")

def output():
    while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        print "hi"

input()
output()
```

You are calling `input()` which is not actually your function name. It's `user_input()`. Also, once `user_input()` is called, `output()` will never be called because the `while True` condition in `user_input()` is always True, meaning it never exits outside the function.

Also, if you want to do something with multithreading, but you don't understand classes in Python, you should probably do a tutorial related to classes.

Take a look at this other [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861515/python-raw-input-and-print-in-a-thread) on a multithreaded program.